# Regarding error numbers in Linux

Tags: c, linux

Is there any link or material where I can learn more about the different error numbers in Linux ??

At present in man errno I get a single line for each error number but I would like to know the conditions or chances for which particular error occurs (A more detailed description in short words)

For e.g.

```
EADDRNOTAVAIL 99 /* Cannot assign requested address */
```

Above error occurs when a socket tried to bind to ip-address which is not present locally in the machine .. Similarly for all other errors is there any wiki or material for detailed information ??

Answer (score 9):

Well, since errors generally occur while doing something, your best bet is to look up the `man` page for "something".

For example, if you get back an `errno` of 34 from your `fscanf()` call, you would first do:

```
grep 34 $(find /usr/include -name '*errno*h')
```

to figure out what the error was:

```
/usr/include/bits/errno.h:#define ERANGE 34 /* Math result not representable. */
/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h:#define ERANGE 34 /* Math result not ... */
```

Then, looking at the `man` page for `fscanf()`, you see:

```
ERANGE - The result of an integer conversion would exceed the size
         that can be stored in the corresponding integer type.
```

and you would (hopefully) be able to figure it out from there.

If you want a list of the errors and (brief) description, modify the `grep` above as follows:

```
grep define $(find /usr/include -name '*errno*h') | less
```

and browse the output.

And, if you still don't know about the error and what caused it (the descriptions are a little terse, I'll agree), I would just bung it (e.g., `EADDRNOTAVAIL`) into that little dialog box in the top right corner of your browser<sup>1</sup> and you'll get back something like [this](http://www.wlug.org.nz/EADDRNOTAVAIL) (or many other wonderful pages):

> **Cannot assign requested address**
>   You are attempting to `bind(2)` to a local address that isn't local. For example if the IP addresses of a machine are `127.0.0.1` and `1.2.3.4` and you're trying to bind to `1.2.3.5`, you are going to get this error. Check to make sure the address you are trying to bind to exists on the machine you are trying to bind it from.
>   This error can also come up if you're doing a "pre-bound connect", where you're first binding to a local port, then doing an outbound connect with a socket. If the local port is already connected to the given remote IP and port (i.e., there's already an identical socketpair), you'll receive this error (value = 99 on Linux).
>   4 pages link to `EADDRNOTAVAIL`:
>        - bind(2)
>        - connect(2)
>        - setsockopt(2)
>        - packet(7)

Go ahead, try it with other error values as well, it's not too bad.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> You *are* using Firefox, right? :-)</sup>

Comment: Firefox it is!! Nice explanation btw.

Answer (score 3):

Error codes are fairly generic, and are meaningful only within the context of a particular function. So there isn't much advantage in learning all the error codes, as they may mean subtly different things for different functions and have to be handled differently anyway.

"ERRORS" section in the function's man page will tell you what codes are possible for its return values or `errno` and why they occur.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you Alex ... But the errors section in every man page still has the same single line ... :(

Comment: @codingfreak Many of them may be the same, but not necessarily. For example `EPERM` is different for `man 2 open` and `man 2 pthread_create` and have to be handled differently.

Answer (score 0):

Its API specfic. I have not heard about a generic error list. However :

```
Many functions provide an error number in errno, which has type int
and is defined in <errno.h>.
```

So you can have a look at the header file [errno.h](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/errno.h.html).
Similarly [Glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Error-Reporting.html#GError) has different codes for error reporting.

EDIT: 
Well if you already know the error code then you can always google to get more information on that error, if you find man page unsatisfactory.

Comment: But I am more intrested in error specified in man errno not specific to any third party application ... like glib

Comment: @codingfreak: You can look at the link for the file errno.h.

Answer (score 0):

If it's GLIBC, try using `%m` in a printf() statement:

```
#include <errno.h>
...
int fh = fopen(...);
if (0 > fh) printf("Couldn't open the file: %d, %m\n", errno);
```

Very useful.

Comment: Itemizing all the locations of the source error codes would be an enormous, and continuously out of date date endeavor: are you writing your own driver and want to be sure you are choosing the right error codes?

Answer (score 0):

As other posters have suggested, the best source for decoding what errors really mean in context is the appropriate man page. For networking protocols, the appropriate man page may be something other than the system call; for IP sockets, try ip(7), which gives a tiny bit more information:

```
   EADDRNOTAVAIL
          A nonexistent interface was requested or  the  requested  source
          address was not local.
```

More error codes are described in tcp(7) and udp(7).

Answer (score 0):

this program can also do the trick..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
        int i= 0 ;

        for ( i = 0 ; i<=132; i++ )
        {
                printf("no %d == %s \n", i , strerror(i));
        }
}
```

> ```
> no 0 == Success
> no 1 == Operation not permitted
> no 2 == No such file or directory
> no 3 == No such process
> no 4 == Interrupted system call
> no 5 == Input/output error
> no 6 == No such device or address
> no 7 == Argument list too long
> no 8 == Exec format error
> no 9 == Bad file descriptor
> no 10 == No child processes
> no 11 == Resource temporarily unavailable
> no 12 == Cannot allocate memory
> no 13 == Permission denied
> no 14 == Bad address
> no 15 == Block device required
> no 16 == Device or resource busy
> no 17 == File exists
> no 18 == Invalid cross-device link
> no 19 == No such device
> no 20 == Not a directory
> no 21 == Is a directory
> no 22 == Invalid argument
> no 23 == Too many open files in system
> no 24 == Too many open files
> no 25 == Inappropriate ioctl for device
> no 26 == Text file busy
> no 27 == File too large
> no 28 == No space left on device
> no 29 == Illegal seek
> no 30 == Read-only file system
> no 31 == Too many links
> no 32 == Broken pipe
> no 33 == Numerical argument out of domain
> no 34 == Numerical result out of range
> no 35 == Resource deadlock avoided
> no 36 == File name too long
> no 37 == No locks available
> no 38 == Function not implemented
> no 39 == Directory not empty
> no 40 == Too many levels of symbolic links
> no 41 == Unknown error 41
> no 42 == No message of desired type
> no 43 == Identifier removed
> no 44 == Channel number out of range
> no 45 == Level 2 not synchronized
> no 46 == Level 3 halted
> no 47 == Level 3 reset
> no 48 == Link number out of range
> no 49 == Protocol driver not attached
> no 50 == No CSI structure available
> no 51 == Level 2 halted
> no 52 == Invalid exchange
> no 53 == Invalid request descriptor
> no 54 == Exchange full
> no 55 == No anode
> no 56 == Invalid request code
> no 57 == Invalid slot
> no 58 == Unknown error 58
> no 59 == Bad font file format
> no 60 == Device not a stream
> no 61 == No data available
> no 62 == Timer expired
> no 63 == Out of streams resources
> no 64 == Machine is not on the network
> no 65 == Package not installed
> no 66 == Object is remote
> no 67 == Link has been severed
> no 68 == Advertise error
> no 69 == Srmount error
> no 70 == Communication error on send
> no 71 == Protocol error
> no 72 == Multihop attempted
> no 73 == RFS specific error
> no 74 == Bad message
> no 75 == Value too large for defined data type
> no 76 == Name not unique on network
> no 77 == File descriptor in bad state
> no 78 == Remote address changed
> no 79 == Can not access a needed shared library
> no 80 == Accessing a corrupted shared library
> no 81 == .lib section in a.out corrupted
> no 82 == Attempting to link in too many shared libraries
> no 83 == Cannot exec a shared library directly
> no 84 == Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
> no 85 == Interrupted system call should be restarted
> no 86 == Streams pipe error
> no 87 == Too many users
> no 88 == Socket operation on non-socket
> no 89 == Destination address required
> no 90 == Message too long
> no 91 == Protocol wrong type for socket
> no 92 == Protocol not available
> no 93 == Protocol not supported
> no 94 == Socket type not supported
> no 95 == Operation not supported
> no 96 == Protocol family not supported
> no 97 == Address family not supported by protocol
> no 98 == Address already in use
> no 99 == Cannot assign requested address
> no 100 == Network is down
> no 101 == Network is unreachable
> no 102 == Network dropped connection on reset
> no 103 == Software caused connection abort
> no 104 == Connection reset by peer
> no 105 == No buffer space available
> no 106 == Transport endpoint is already connected
> no 107 == Transport endpoint is not connected
> no 108 == Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown
> no 109 == Too many references: cannot splice
> no 110 == Connection timed out
> no 111 == Connection refused
> no 112 == Host is down
> no 113 == No route to host
> no 114 == Operation already in progress
> no 115 == Operation now in progress
> no 116 == Stale NFS file handle
> no 117 == Structure needs cleaning
> no 118 == Not a XENIX named type file
> no 119 == No XENIX semaphores available
> no 120 == Is a named type file
> no 121 == Remote I/O error
> no 122 == Disk quota exceeded
> no 123 == No medium found
> no 124 == Wrong medium type
> no 125 == Operation canceled
> no 126 == Required key not available
> no 127 == Key has expired
> no 128 == Key has been revoked
> no 129 == Key was rejected by service
> no 130 == Owner died
> no 131 == State not recoverable
> no 132 == Unknown error 132
> ```

Comment: Just curious - why did you choose 132?